# Importing Contracts

Tags: solidity, contract-development, addresses

I am just struggling to understand why the constructor is done like it is and what is it doing?

I am trying to implement something similar as am looking to find the address of the contract, called DiceGame in this example.

[image: Code snippet]

Answer (score 0):

Here, the constructor is asking for an address called `diceGameAddress` which will, hopefully, will be deployed `DiceGame` contract.

Now the line `diceGame = DiceGame(diceGameAddress)` is actually creating an instance of this deployed contract in this contract to be used later.

And finally, the address is being updated in the `dice` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor should be

```js
contract RidgeRoll is Ownable {
    DiceGame public diceGame;

    constructor(DiceGame diceGameAddress) {
        diceGame = diceGameAddress;
    }
}
```

then you can the functions of DiceGame inside RidgeRoll like this :

```js
function use() public {
    diceGame.functionToUse();
}
```